# How to Change position of default zoom tool of Open Layers using css?

Tags: css, openlayers, openlayers-3, openlayers-6

How to Change position of default zoom tool of Open Layers using css?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhiBQ.png)

Comment: Change ` .ol-zoom`  as in .https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/center.html  (if you need to right or bottom align you must set left or top to auto).

Answer (score 2):

To put the zoom control in the upper left corner of the map, set:

```
.map .ol-zoom {
  top: 10px;
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;

}
```

(as @Mike indicated in his comment)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vobej3cs/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.OSM()
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.41, 8.82]),
    zoom: 4
  })
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.map .ol-zoom {
  top: 10px;
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.14.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.14.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  <title>OpenLayers example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

adding this CSS moves the zoom buttons to the right

```css
div.ol-zoom {
    top: .5em;
    right: .5em;
    left: auto;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).